# Opengl - appending to a texture

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I want to create a texture system where I **add** to a texture, *not* overwrite it. My texture has integer values (32 bit). What I want: Ex. I have an integer pixel with bits 100, I want to add 10 to it so it becomes 110.

My current implementation has two textures, one with the previous texture, and a texture to write on. The previous texture's values are read and then rewritten with the new data. Is there a better method to do so because using two textures feel very inefficient?

Comment: "Appending" is a very poor choice of words here; appending implies growing some collection, but this is just adding together texel values. The two-texture method is probably fine; You might be able to get more efficiency out of image load/store, but that's fairly new and I don't know enough about it to help.

Comment: I changed up my question to take that into consideration, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "appending", you could use *additive blending*:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendEquation(GL_FUNC_ADD);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
```

then, the routput of your fragment shader will by added to the current contents of the color buffer. If you use a FBO to render into the texture, you can directly add to this texture.

You should just be careful to not create any feedback loops, so your fragment shader's result should not depend on any sample of the very same texture you render to.

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comment, the texture in question has `GL_RED_INTEGER` format. Unfortunately, the blending is only applied on floating-point color buffers (including normalized integers), and never on unnormalized integers.

However, there is another potential approach. The rules for the "feedback loops" I mentioned before have been relaxed with recent OpenGL. The extension [GL_ARB_texture_barrier](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_barrier.txt) explicitely allowes a fragment shader to read pixels from the same texture it is writing to:

> Specifically, the values of rendered fragments are undefined if any
>       shader stage fetches texels and the same texels are written via fragment
>       shader outputs, even if the reads and writes are not in the same Draw
>       call, **unless any of the following exceptions apply**:
>
> - The reads and writes are from/to disjoint sets of texels (after
>       accounting for texture filtering rules).
> - **There is only a single read and write of each texel, and the read is in
>       the fragment shader invocation that writes the same texel (e.g. using
>       "texelFetch2D(sampler, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);").**
> - [...]

This extension has been promoted to a core feature of OpenGL 4.5. This is quite new and not available on a lot of platforms, so it is unclear if you can use it...

Comment: Will this work with bitwise integers? Say I have a red integer with bits 100, and try to add 10, will it become 110? If so this is exactly what I need

Comment: Unfortunately not. Blending is simply not applied if your color buffer format is unnormalized integer... You should add that requirement into the original question. Your example values also did not strongly imply integers... ;)

Comment: @Jas: I updated my answer with another suggestion. YMMV

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts derhass :), Ive read about this feature too but unfortunately I am  using opengl 2. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @Jas: "This is quite new" No, it is not "quite new". This has been available as NV_texture_barrier for some time. And that extension is not only implemented on [lots of Intel and AMD hardware](http://delphigl.de/glcapsviewer/listreports2.php?listreportsbyextension=GL_NV_texture_barrier), it's even [on MacOSX](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/).

Comment: @Jas Depending on what exactly you need, you may be able to use logic ops. For example, if you could limit your values to powers of 2, you could "add" them with the `GL_OR` operation. See `glLogicOp()`.

Comment: Thx @Reto Koradi, I tried your suggestion but I get the error "WARNING: Ignoring GL_OR logic op on GL_UNSIGNED_INT renderbuffer". Will it work if I change it to GL_INT? Or even GL_FLOAT?

Comment: Yes it worked! Thx Reto Koradi, I had to change my texture type to a float, integers didnt work. Thx for the help!

Comment: @Jas That's somewhat odd. I was just looking it up, and the only obvious restriction I found in the spec was: "Logical operation has no effect on a ﬂoating-point destination color buffer."

Comment: I am using a linux system... maybe my driver has issues.... not sure lol. But the important thing is that it works for now lol

Comment: @Jas: well, when you can switch your texture format to floating point, the initial suggestion with the blending will also work... ;)

Comment: @derhass, yes thanks it worked with your inital suggestion lol! Reto Koradi was right, it didnt work with floats but it didnt work with integers either for some reason. But it works well now thx. This answer works